# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'alert'

Tags: javascript

Greetings to the community, i'm new in javascript and i want to figure out why this code throws me this error, thank you!

```
"use strict";
var myFunction = function(){
document.alert("hola");
};

myFunction();
```

the console(chrome) says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'alert'

I've used jshint to correct any sintax errors, but it seems to have no errors.

Comment: you probably mean `window.alert` ?

Comment: For future reference, all globals (ie, "JSON") are found under `window`, ie `window.alert`, not `document`.

Comment: @Katana314 if your JS environment is a web browser...

Comment: @Alnitak Correct. Of course, if you're running something in Rhino, for instance, alert and most of the globals you'd ever count on won't work anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `alert()` belongs to the `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `alert()` method belongs to the `window` object, rather than the `document`:

```
alert('hola');
```

Though you *can*, if for some reason you wanted to, use `window.alert`:

```
window.alert('hola');
```

Comment: the first half of your answer is just confusing, IMHO.

Comment: that's much better!  I actually like to use `window.alert` explicitly - 1. it's more efficient because it avoids a scope climb, 2. it allows me to just tell `jshint` about the `window` global and not every method within it.

Answer (score 1):

The `alert` function is a method of the `window` object, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.alert).

Answer (score 0):

Alert isn't a method of document is a method of window
Instead of this:

```
document.alert("hola");
```

try this:

```
window.alert("hola");
```

Comment: not my downvote, but no, you don't "have to use the function alert alone" - it's a method of the `window` object, so you can use `window.alert`